# What is the right way to set WWW-Authenticate header in rails response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the right way to set WWW-Authenticate header in rails response?

Currently I do it this way:

```
    headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Basic realm="My Realm")
    render :json => {:message =>I18n.t("errors.messages.authorization_error")}, :status => :unauthorized
```

I think that there is a more simple way to set this header using rails api. Without accessing header dictionary directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing, but rails does have HTTP authenication baked in.  Please see this link: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic

Comment: Here is the implementation of 401 response http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html#method-i-authentication_request

Comment: But I finally decided to create my own helper method since I return json response inside body.